# Using Windows Azure in a local Dev Mode with PHP

Tags: azure

We are trying to evaluate and eventually migrate to the windows azure cloud platform.
I am stumbling on the installation process...
I'm currently following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2010/02/26/getting-started-with-php-on-windows-azure-tools-for-eclipse.aspx) tutorial.

I can't get the Windows development Fabric interface working like on this picture.

[image]

When I install the app fabric sdk (downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19925)) I get no .exe program to simulate the cloud...
I installed Windows AppFabric which is not what I need (I think).
I keep on being directed on AppPlatformInstaller which do not install what I need but I'm sure is part of my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are downloading wrong SDK. For Windows Azure Cloud platform you must download and install [Windows Azure SDK And Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/).
Then you will have a folder %Program Files%\Windows Azure SDK\v1.5\bin. There will be devfabric and devstore folders, under which the local development Frabric and Development Storage executables will reside.

Then if you are targeting .NET based solutions, you will have new project templates in Visual Studio, and everything shall be running smoothly. On the other hand, if you are targeting open source solutions you might want to follow the like provided by Ben.
As for Windows AppFabric - yes, it is wrong in terms that it is not related to Windows Azure at all.

Let us know if you have any issues when downloading and installing latest [Windows Azure SDK And Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/)

Comment: hum i have to confirm it tomorow but i think i have the %Program Files%\Windows Azure SDK\v1.5\ folder but not the bin one !

Comment: If that is the case I suggest that you uninstall and install new fresh copy of Windows Azure SDK (latest) from the link in my original answer.

Comment: Ok i must say that you solved my problem thank's a lot.  Obviously my webPlatformInstaller was not the up to date one!

Comment: Cool. I'm glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the docs available from the Microsoft Interoperability Team. They maintain an entire site dedicated to running PHP on Windows Azure

http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/build-and-deploy-a-windows-azure-php-application

Basically to get it working just install the Windows Azure SDK and with Windows Azure SDK for PHP. Build your PHP application and then run the package command. Your PHP application will be rolled into a Windows Azure project and launched in the local dev fabric